# PayPal issue with my UCP

Tags: php, paypal, integration, ucp

I'm currently having this issue, and I was told to post here.

Basically I have a UCP (User Control Panel) for a gameserver which I am running, the issue I am having with it is that:

Well, basically there is a donation page. On that page there is a list of items, in order to get them you have to have credits, in order to have credits you must add them, using real money. So there is a button called "Get more Credits", once you click on that a popup comes up saying how much credits you'd like to add. After you enter the amount, you press enter and then it proceeds you on to the next page.

The issue I am having though is that it's not transferring over the amount entered in the UCP to the PayPal page. I've tried to get help on this, but still having the issue. Hopefully somebody here can help me out so I can get this fixed.

I attached a link to the `buy.php` which contains all of the code. I also included the `Paypal.ipn.inc` and the `ipn.php` file.

Hopefully someone has an answer for me, thanks!

**Files:**

**buy.php**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtl4bq8y69bi183/buy.php

**Paypal.inc.php**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0inzawdfb0buofm/paypal.inc-1.php

Comment: Hey Javun, it would be good if you could show us what the output of the raw `$_GET['creditAmount']` and processed `$price` variables are. And also a screen shot of what you see when experiencing the problem.

Comment: @EM-Creations - This is what I see after entering the amount I want, `http://i.imgur.com/s6k2AHi.png` This is what I get from `$_GET['creditAmount'] Raw credit data: 3 Used credit data:` I'm not sure what you mean about the $price variables.

Comment: Okay, the output of `$price` is in that email output, and it's coming up as blank. Which implies there's something wrong when converted `$_GET['creditAmount']` to `$price`..

Comment: @EM-Creations I've added the buy.php file in the main post above, the link to download it. If you could take a look at the code and see if there may be something in it causing the issue would be appreciated. Keep me updated, I'm looking forward to resolving this ASAP :)

Comment: @EM-Creations I did some editing to the code and got this `Raw credit data: 3 Used credit data: 0 `